# Removing application from service fabric cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I tried removing application from service fabric using service fabric explorer.

I deleted my application using Delete Application action.
Then When I tried Unprovision application type I got error saying,

> Error: Application Type of version 1.0.0 could not be unprovisioned as
>   it still contains active applications.

I could see that even after deleting the application , the actor service inside the application is still active in some of the nodes. [Am attaching a screenshot of my service fabric explorer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/set2k.png)

Any help regarding completely removing the applications?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This can happen if services in your application don't play nice by not shutting down when requested by the platform, for example by ignoring the cancellation token in RunAsync.

Here's a quick PowerShell script that will go through an application and force remove all replicas of all stateful services:

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint localhost:19000

$nodes = Get-ServiceFabricNode

foreach($node in $nodes)
{
    $replicas = Get-ServiceFabricDeployedReplica -NodeName $node.NodeName -ApplicationName "fabric:/MyApp"

    foreach ($replica in $replicas)
    {
        Remove-ServiceFabricReplica -ForceRemove -NodeName $node.NodeName -PartitionId $replica.Partitionid -ReplicaOrInstanceId $replica.ReplicaOrInstanceId
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine. Don't forget to replace "fabric:/MyApp" by your own application name.

Answer (score 2):

Go to http://localhost:19080/-->Expand Cluster-->Applications-->Service
Click on the 3 dots beside service and select option "Delete service"
Similarly delete the application and then unprovision the type