# Service Fabric - DeleteServiceAsync timing out

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I am spawning several ASF microservices to run some process. Once the process is done, I am deleting those services using `DeleteServiceAsync` by using following code. Almost 98% of the time, everything works fine. However, 2% of the time, I run into timeout issue and the microservices stucks in deleting state with Idle Secondary replica. Thanks in advance for any suggestions to resolve this issue.

```
using (FabricClient fc = new FabricClient())
{
    fc.ServiceManager.DeleteServiceAsync(deleteServiceDescription, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: do you have a code path in RunAsync that could take a long time and doesn't regularly check the cancellationtoken?

Comment: The cancellationtoken passed to RunAsync is not used. RunAsync starts another task that could take long time. Do I need to pass this cancellation token to new task that I start within RunAsync so that this can be terminated all tasks when cancellation is requested?

Comment: Yes, pass it to the operation and check it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could force drop the offending replicas with something like the solution provided to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35765141/removing-application-from-service-fabric-cluster), but that's usually a bad idea and shouldn't be done in production.

This stuck state usually indicates that the service is having a problem in its shutdown path. Have you debugged this locally? Just creating and deleting the service in a loop until it happens should be enough to show you where it is.