# Force delete of Service Fabric application

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am having issues during development where an exception during service start up causes the application to get stuck in an error state. This prevents further debugging. I can't seem to delete the application through the cluster management portal either, it just times out.

The only way I've found to fix is to reset the cluster, which takes a few minutes and deletes all other applications from the cluster as well.

What's the correct way to force delete of an individual application?

Comment: You can remove services & applications easily using [the portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-visualizing-your-cluster#actions)

Comment: @PeterBons my problem is that the application wasn't responding to delete commands from the portal. I've edited the question to make this clearer.

Comment: Ah ok. Coincide or not, but we run into the same issue earlier today. I now see your comments, we used the powershell script form here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35765141/removing-application-from-service-fabric-cluster/35880883#35880883

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created the following powershell script which seems to do the trick:

```
param([string]$applicationName = "SomeAppName", [string]$version = "1.0.0")

$applicationUri = "fabric:/" + $applicationName
$applicationTypeName = $applicationName + "Type"

Connect-ServiceFabricCluster localhost:19000

Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Removing $applicationUri from local cluster"

Remove-ServiceFabricApplication -ApplicationName fabric:/$applicationName

Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Removing $applicationTypeName (v$version) from local cluster"

Unregister-ServiceFabricApplicationType -ApplicationTypeName $applicationTypeName -ApplicationTypeVersion $version

Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Complete"
```

Can be called like so:

```
.\Delete-SF-App.ps1 -applicationName "MyService" -version "1.0.0"
```

**EDIT:**

If the above doesn't work then the below powershell command can be used to remove individual replicas:

```
$nodes = Get-ServiceFabricNode

foreach($node in $nodes)
{
    $replicas = Get-ServiceFabricDeployedReplica -NodeName $node.NodeName -ApplicationName $applicationName
    foreach ($replica in $replicas)
    {
        Remove-ServiceFabricReplica -ForceRemove -NodeName $node.NodeName -PartitionId $replica.Partitionid -ReplicaOrInstanceId $replica.ReplicaOrInstanceId
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work for me - I've even added -Force -ForceDelete parameters to Remove-ServiceFabricApplication and it still times out on my local dev cluster

Comment: @AdriaandeBeer I added an edit to show how to remove individual replicas as well - if you run this it should completely remove the problem application

Answer (score 0):

*Please ignore this answer if you aren't using Visual Studio for development and debugging.*

I know the question is already answered but have you tried to change **Application Debug Mode** setting in Visual Studio to **Remove Application**?